# How to do a sequential for loop in Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am using ember 2.1 and I would to apply an action for every line of a text file that I get using the Javascript FileReader api. Would anyone know how to do that? 
-When I try using "foreach" the execution is not sequential: the program does not wait for one line to be recorded before starting treating the next line; hence I get lines skipped and have no control on the execution;
-I tried a simple for loop, but it didn't work and I read that they are not possible in Ember actions;
-When I use a recursive call to an Ember action (in the following code: *saveNew(lines)*, called first by *openFile(event)*), another problem happen: every new line replaces the last one instead of being added to the last one, and at the end only the last line is recorded.

```
  saveNew(lines) {
    const promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

      var line = lines.shift();
      var cols = line.split(';');
      var c = 0;
      var patt = /[A-z ]/g;
      var result = patt.test(line);
      if (result == true) {

        this.model.name = cols[0];
        console.log("named");
        this.model.url = cols[1];
        console.log("urled");
        this.model.description = cols[2];
        console.log("descripted");
        console.log(cols[2]);
        this.get('model').save().then((source) => {
          console.log("in the insertion");

          this.send('toast', 'Source créée.');
          console.log("wooouu");
          this.transitionToRoute('signed-in.sources.source', source);
          console.log("incredible");

        }).then(() => {
          setTimeout(() => {
            resolve(lines);
          }, 1000);
        });
      } else {
        resolve(lines);
      }
    });

    promise1.then((value) => {
      if (value.length > 0) {
        this.send('saveNew', value);
      }
    });
  },

  openFile(event) {
    console.log('upload');
    var input = event.target;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    console.log('ici');

    reader.addEventListener("load", (function(e) {
      var text = e.target.result;
      text.replace(/(\r\n)|\r|\n/g, '\n'); //normalisation des caractères de retour à la ligne
      var lines = text.split(/\n+/g); //séparation du texte du fichier en lignes
      var insnumb = 0;
      const taille = lines.length;
      this.send('saveNew', lines);
    }).bind(this));
    reader.readAsText(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use of [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await) could help with promises and run stuff in sequential order

Not sure if this would help:

```
var e = {
  async saveNew (lines) {
    const pattern = /[A-z ]/g
    
    for (const line of lines) {
      if (pattern.test(line)) {
        const cols = line.split(';')
        
        this.model.name = cols[0]
        this.model.url = cols[1]
        this.model.description = cols[2]
        
        const source = await this.get('model').save()
        this.send('toast', 'Source créée.')
        this.transitionToRoute('signed-in.sources.source', source)
      }
    }
  },
  
  async openFile (event) {
    const [file] = event.target.files
    if (!file) return
    const text = await file.text()
    // Normalisation des caractères de retour à la ligne
    text.replace(/(\r\n)|\r|\n/g, '\n') 
    // Séparation du texte du fichier en lignes
    const lines = text.split(/\n+/g)
    this.send('saveNew', lines)
  }
}
```